# Magento 403 forbidden error in console

Tags: magento-1.9, error, console

I am getting following error in my Browser's console.

Any suggestions are welcome.

> "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - www.example.com/skin/frontend/mytheme/default/"

Comment: Check the permission of this folder..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like permissions error.

Provide full permissions to your site's root directory recursively or try giving Magento's standard permissions as one of the code below suggests.

Navigate to your root directory through Terminal:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Now try refreshing in the browser.

**Hope this works for you.**

Comment: files owner what is matter , not chmod...

Comment: `chmod` is required for changing permissions on any Ubuntu server, I guess you know that.

Comment: you just dont understand whats going on here , the issue is probably related to directory listing, cause i dont see any files at the end of the url, another problem if you have files access issues then the user who owns the files is wrong, you need to `chown -R phpuser:phpuser *`

Comment: I applied the solution above and it fixed the problem, besides it is on server, so it cannot allow to change ownership, as you said.